# How can I add some content to a file whose filename contains space in bash script?

Tags: bash, file, space

My code likes

```
target_file="target/middle dir/filename"
echo -e "Something New\n$(cat $target_file)" > "$target_file"
```

It failed with error:

```
cat target/middle: Is a directory
cat : No such file or directory
```

cat cannot handle a file path with space in it.

And I have tried following:

```
echo -e "Something New\n$(cat \"$target_file\")" > "$target_file"
```

No luck.

And solution?

Comment: Just double quote all your variable, eg `"$target_file"` and not `$target_file` the double quotes are not just syntatic sugar, it is vital to shell scripts... In your case the command `$(...)` substitution introduces a new set of quoting if a variable is inside it. Put a valid [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) and paste your script at https://shellcheck.net for validation/recommendation.

Comment: Just for information: In the version which you have tried, you made it even worse: The ´\"` actually passes a literal quote to `cat`, while still splitting `$target_file` into two words. `cat` therefore looks for two files, one named `"target/middle` and the other one named `dir/filename"`. If you find  the bash rule (parameter expansion comes before word splitting) inconvenient due to the frequent need for quoting, you may consider switching to zsh, which has the policy "word splitting before parameter expansion".

Answer (score 1):

Apart from your quote issues, reading from and writing to the same file in one command may also raise issues. The following is one way the script can be written:

```
target_file="target/middle dir/filename"
{ echo "Something New"; cat "$target_file"; } > "$target_file".temp~ &&
        mv "$target_file".temp~ "$target_file"
```

Also, you shouldn't use `echo -e`; it is not portable and, for your case, may have issues if the file contents contain backslash characters (`-e` would attempt to interpret them).

Answer (score 0):

The closest to your solution would be:

```
echo -e "Something New\n$(cat "$target_file")" > "$target_file"
```

However for me this one looks better:

```
echo -e "Something New\n`cat "$target_file"`" > "$target_file"
```

You can also use sed (to avoid calling command in the command):

```
sed -i '1iSomething New' "$target_file"
```